# What type of plastic is best for outdoor usage?

Tags: outdoor, plastic

What type of plastic is best for outdoor usage? Like resistant to constant sunlight and water exposure and strong enough. It will be used to encolse part of (small size bird) aviary. Also please specify how much thickness will be enough for it.

Comment: What are you using the plastic for?

Comment: It will be used to encolsed part of an aviary.

Comment: Updated the question. please see.

Answer (score 1):

Corrugated roofing panels, either clear polycarbonate or fiberglass skylight panels, should do the job. I'd put more trust in the light/weather resistance of fiberglass than polycarbonate, but both are readily available.

Comment: I want to enclose side of aviary too. How much thick it need to be? and what type?

Comment: Roofing material should be thick enough for walls hung on a supporting frame. The fibreglass stuff is strong enough to walk on. It won't have any value as insulation, or stand up to typhoon winds, but it ought to keep your birds in without trouble.